# How to schedule the uploading of videos to a YouTube Channel?

Tags: python, automation, youtube

I was trying to automate uploading to my YT channel with Python.

The story goes like this:

I had a channel and I upload multiple times a day. But now I'm about to join college and I don't have the time to do the uploading except at weekends.

The editing isn't the problem, it's the uploading I would like to get done. But I don't want to upload all (say) 50 videos on Sunday and none for the rest of the week. and that inconsistency is bad for YT growth.

So my plan was to bunch-edit and produce all those videos on weekend and let a script upload those ready-made videos over the whole week, with an equally spaced interval, periodic and recurring without me telling it every time I want to (for eg. twice a day or five times a day).

The workflow I needed is as follows

1. The Script uploads a video from a specified folder
2. post the video to YT with pre-set data (title, desc., tag...)
3. (Then only if the upload was successful) move that video to another
   folder to avoid re uploading and to keep track (I don't want to
   delete them in case they're needed later)
4. repeat the process every certain hours

I’ve been thinking about ways to create the workflow above,
but I couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

i have the right script for you but can't upload here lol.
import schedule
you can use this library for scheduling a function(the upload function),
but you will can to keep your program run all the time.
or using the microsoft scheduler , which will schedule your whole program.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> This Python code below will recursively upload all video files in the
> `raw_uploads_folder`, wait for the specified interval (`24` hours in
> this example), and then repeat the process. Make sure to replace
> '`path/to/raw_uploads_folder`' and
> '`path/to/successful_uploads_folder`' with the actual paths to your
> folders. Adjust the upload_interval_hours variable according to your
> requirements.

```
import os
import time
from bot_studio import *

def upload_video(video_path, title, description, tags, kid_type):
    # Initialize the YouTube bot
    youtube = bot_studio.youtube()

    # Login using cookies
    cookie_list = 'list of cookies'
    youtube.login_cookie(cookies=cookie_list)

    # Upload the video
    response = youtube.upload(title=title, video_path=video_path, kid_type=kid_type, description=description, tags=tags, type='Public')
    body = response['body']
    video_link = body['VideoLink']

    return video_link

def move_video(source_path, destination_path):
    # Move the video from source to destination folder
    os.rename(source_path, destination_path)

# Define folders
raw_uploads_folder = 'path/to/raw_uploads_folder'
successful_uploads_folder = 'path/to/successful_uploads_folder'

# Define video details
description = 'It displays how to upload video to youtube using datakund'
tags = ['upload', 'tutorial', 'datakund']
kid_type = "Yes, it's made for kids"

# Define the number of hours to wait between uploads
upload_interval_hours = 24  # Change this value as needed

while True:
    # Iterate through all files in raw_uploads_folder
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(raw_uploads_folder):
        for file in files:
            # Upload each video file
            video_file = os.path.join(root, file)
            title = os.path.splitext(file)[0]  # Extract title from file name
            video_link = upload_video(video_file, title, description, tags, kid_type)

            # Move the uploaded video to successful_uploads_folder if upload was successful
            if video_link:
                move_video(video_file, os.path.join(successful_uploads_folder, file))

    # Wait for the specified interval before next upload
    time.sleep(upload_interval_hours * 3600)  # Convert hours to seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can also follow the `README.md` file on this GitHub project for a
> similar alternative:
> https://github.com/linouk23/youtube_uploader_selenium

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35639714)